# Accepted as string despite being inputted as integer through nextInt()

Tags: java, string, input, integer, decimalformat

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.System;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StorePrice
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        int taxRate, markupRate, price;
        Scanner prompt = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat decimal = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

        System.out.print("Input the original price: ");
        price = prompt.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input the markup rate: ");
        markupRate = prompt.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input the tax rate: ");
        taxRate = prompt.nextInt();

        markupRate = decimal.format(markupRate);
        taxRate = decimal.format(taxRate);

        System.out.print("Original price: " + price + "\n");
        System.out.print("Markup rate: " + markupRate + "\n");
        System.out.print("Selling price: " + (price + (price*markupRate)) + "\n");
        System.out.print("Tax rate: " + taxRate + "\n");
        System.out.print("Tax: " + (price*taxRate) + "\n");
        System.out.print("Final price: " + ((price*markupRate) + (price*taxRate)) + "\n");
    }
}
```

Hello, I'm new to OOP and Java itself and I'm having problems with inputted data types through nextInt();. The error goes like this:

```
C:\Stuffs\Codes\Java\StorePrice.java:25: error: incompatible types
        markupRate = decimal.format(markupRate);
                                   ^
  required: int
  found:    String
C:\Stuffs\Codes\Java\StorePrice.java:26: error: incompatible types
        taxRate = decimal.format(taxRate);
                                ^
  required: int
  found:    String
2 errors
```

Why is it still an string despite being inputted as an integer? Where here does the problem lie here?

EDIT: I forgot to add that I am strictly instructed to declare `price`, `markupRate` and `taxRate` as integers in the code.

Comment: `markupRate` and `taxRate` are declared as types of `int`, but you're trying to assign `String`s to them, this doesn't make sense.  You probably need seperate variables to store the formatted results in which are `String`s

Comment: Sorry, but I forgot to tell that I strictly have to initialize them as integers from what I have been instructed to.

Comment: Sure, so use different variables to store the formatting result

Answer (score 1):

You have to be aware of the return type of the methods that you call when assinging it to a variable (when it is not created by you, you can look it up in the documentation). In this case you are trying to assign the INT markupRate and tax rate to a String variable returned from decimal.format(int). So what you have to do, it is just to create some String variables to hold the string returned, but you still need the ints as parameters to be formated.
try this:

```
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
       int  taxRate, markupRate, price;
        String sMarkupRate, sTaxRate;
        String sSellingPrice, sTax, sFinalPrice;
        Scanner prompt = new Scanner(System.in);
        DecimalFormat decimal = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

        System.out.print("Input the original price: ");
        price = prompt.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input the markup rate: ");
        markupRate = prompt.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input the tax rate: ");
        taxRate = prompt.nextInt();

        sMarkupRate = decimal.format(markupRate);
        sTaxRate = decimal.format(taxRate);
        sSellingPrice = decimal.format(price + (price*markupRate));
        sTax = decimal.format((price*taxRate));
        sFinalPrice = decimal.format((price*markupRate) + (price*taxRate));


        System.out.print("Original price: " + price + "\n");
        System.out.print("Markup rate: " + sMarkupRate  + "\n");
        System.out.print("Selling price: " + sSellingPrice + "\n");
        System.out.print("Tax rate: " + sTaxRate + "\n");
        System.out.print("Tax: " + sTax + "\n");
        System.out.print("Final price: " + sFinalPrice + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe better to change to `String sMarkupRate = decimal.format(markupRate);`  i.e. declared closest to where you use

Comment: True. it is better to use local variables rather than global ones whenever it is possible

Comment: Nothing to do with local vs global variables.  I am saying that there is no point declaring your variable at the top of a method, when your declare and initialise in one go.  With you code, the reader of the code has to search for the variable `sMarkupRate` to find out what type of variable it is.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that my initialization with the variables taxRate, markupRate and price should strictly be integer. I tried doing `markupRate = Integer.parseInt(decimal.format(markupRate));` but it somewhat still did not work and is still considered a string as a return